# Cubesviewer configuration for proper authentication

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm trying to configure cubesviewer and try out the setup. 
 I've got the app installed running, along with cubes slicer app too.
However, when I visit the home page

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cubesviewer/
it fails popping up an error "Error occurred while accessing the data server"

Debugging with the browser console, shows a http status 403 error with the url http://localhost:8000/cubesviewer/view/list/

After some googling and reading, I figured I'll need to add rest frame auth settings. (as mentioned here.).

Now after running migrate and runserver, I get 401 error on that url.

Clearly I'm missing something with settings.py , Can somebody help me out.
I'm using the cubesviewer tag v0.10 from the github repo.
And find my settings here. http://dpaste.com/2G5VB5K

P.S: I've verified Cubes slicer works separately on its' own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced this. This is error may occur when you use different URL to access a website and to access related resources. For security reasons, browsers allow to access resources from exactly the same host as the page you are viewing.

Seems you are accessing the app via `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, but you have configured CubesViewer to tell clients to access the data backend via `http://localhost:8000`. While it's the same IP address, they are different strings.

Try accessing the app as `http://localhost:8000`.

If you deploy to a different server, you need to adjust settings. Here are the relevant configuration options, now with more comments:

```
# Base Cubes Server URL.
# Your Cubes Server needs to be running and listening on this URL, and it needs
# to be accessible to clients of the application.
CUBESVIEWER_CUBES_URL="http://localhost:5000"

# CubesViewer Store backend URL. It should point to this application.
# Note that this must match the URL that you use to access the application,
# otherwise you may hit security issues. If you access your server
# via http://localhost:8000, use the same here. Note that 127.0.0.1 and
# 'localhost' are different strings for this purpose. (If you wish to accept
# requests from different URLs, you may need to add CORS support).
CUBESVIEWER_BACKEND_URL="http://localhost:8000/cubesviewer"
```

Alternatively, you could change `CUBESVIEWER_BACKEND_URL` to `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/cubesviewer"` but I recommend you to use hostnames and not IP addresses for this.

Finally, I haven't yet tested with CORS support, but check [this pull request](https://github.com/jjmontesl/cubesviewer/pull/47/files) if you wish to try that approach.

Comment: Enabling cors support solved the problem for me.. thanks